# How to apply a Django patch?

Tags: django, patch

I am developing an Django application using the Django 1.3.1 release :
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1

I encountered a bug, which has been identified and fixed by the Django team :
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16128

The changeset associated to the bug resolution is located in Django trunk
https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17755

My question is : how can I take advantage of the bug resolution, without upgrading to the Django trunk version ?

There a bunch of files attached to the ticket, the latest is :
https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/16128/16128.diff

I can see that this file is a standard 'diff' file, which can be processed by the 'patch' utility. I tried to apply it on my django 1.3.1 installation (on a dev machine), but it does not work...The source lines (to be replaced) are not exactly the one expected by the diff file.

To which 'start state' does refer this diff file ? In other words, to which django version can it be applied ?

Is there another way than applying it 'manually' ? Even if I apply it manually, I can see that the patched code call new versions of methods not included in the patch...which means that I have to find out, by reading the code, which other files have to be patched, and patch them...

At this point, I think something like : "waow, it's to complicated, let's wait the next release of Django - 1.5, for this ticket - and find a workaround !". But, in other hand, if the patch system exists, it must be possible to apply this patch to my Django 1.3.1 installation...

Did anyone encountered the same kind of problem ? If so, how did you manage it ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This bug was fixed on 2012/03/04, which was two weeks before the release of 1.4. In other words, this fix is included in the 1.4 release.

Comment: Indeed, you are right Daniel ! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually try with the Django 1.4 release, which has been issued a few days ago? I am quite sure it is part of it.

Anyways...you can get the official diff at the changeset page that you referenced - at the bottom there is a link to an unified diff. You can download the patch from there and use it to patch(1) your release (beware that should the Django team release a new security release of Django 1.3, you may have to apply it again). However, those diffs are always against the most recent codebase at the time the patch has been committed. For that reason, sometimes you might have a bad luck (like in the case you have described above) and it may not apply cleanly to the previous release. In such case you would have to track down all the changes required to make it work, which may be pretty much work and might be unacceptable. So there are only three options: find your own way to work the bug around, track all the changes required to apply the patch cleanly, or upgrade to the given revision.

Comment: You are right Daniel, the bug is fixed in Django 1.4 ! And thank you for pointing the three options to apply a 'patch'. No magic !